# Repeat a name for every date in df

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of 63 names `name` and a date variable `df$Date`with 3000 dates, I need to repeat every name in the list for every date in the df?

I've looked around a bit about how to do this but was wondering if anyone had any solutions??

Thanks

EDIT:
I've found a way of doing this with

```
ts <- seq(ymd("2010-01-01"), ymd(Sys.Date()), by="day")
df <- data.frame(Date=ts, Name=Name)
df$Date <- as.character(df$Date)
df2 <- rep.int(df$Date, 63)
df2 <- data.frame(Date=df2, Name=Name)
df$date <- rep.row(df$Date, Name)
```

But this may be a long winded way of doing it?

Comment: Potential solution found above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimal example given below:

```
ts <- seq(ymd("2010-01-01"), ymd("2010-01-03"), by = "day")
names = letters[1:3]

df <- expand.grid(date = ts, name = names)
```